# Error TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' al enviar proyecto a producción

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework, qr

Un saludo y buen día a todos, ojalá me puedan guiar con mi problema. Les comento tengo un lector de QR simple donde cargo la imagen QR y muestro el resultado en pantalla. Funciona normal al ejecutar el proyecto usando el comando ionic serve, pero cuando lo mando a producción con el comando ionic build --prod se genera un error que hace referencia al input:

```
<input #fileinput type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" hidden (change)="handleFile($event.target.files)">
```

El error que se genera es el siguiente: **error TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.** Les adjunto además una captura del error en el cmd:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo el código del tab1.page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      DEMO LECTOR FILE QR
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-content>
    <input #fileinput type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" hidden (change)="handleFile($event.target.files)">
    <ion-button expand="full" (click)="captureImage()">
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="camera"></ion-icon>
      Capturar Imagen
    </ion-button>
    <canvas #canvas hidden></canvas>
    <ion-card *ngIf="scanResult">
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>QR Code</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        {{ scanResult }}
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

Y así tengo el código del tab1.page.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import jsQR from 'jsqr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  @ViewChild('video', { static: false }) video: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: false }) canvas: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fileinput', { static: false }) fileinput: ElementRef;

  canvasElement: any;
  canvasContext: any;
  scanResult = null;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.canvasContext = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
  }

  captureImage() {
    this.fileinput.nativeElement.click();
  }

  handleFile(files: FileList) {
    const file = files.item(0);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      this.canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);
      const imageData = this.canvasContext.getImageData(
        0,
        0,
        this.canvasElement.width,
        this.canvasElement.height
      );
      const code = jsQR(imageData.data, imageData.width, imageData.height, {
        inversionAttempts: 'dontInvert'
      });

      if (code) {
        this.scanResult = code.data;
      }
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
}
```

Tengo la versión de angular 11.2.11 y de ionic 5.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba manejando el Files en la función

en el HTML

```
(change)="handleFile($event)
```

en el typescript

```
handleFile(event): void {
   try {
   const files = event.target.files;
   ...
   } catch {}
}
```

Comment: funcionó :') Sabe si se puede ejecutar la app en servidor Xampp o necesariamente habría que usar Firebase?

Comment: no se mucho sobre eso, yo sirvo las aplicaciones en mi propio servidor pero angular es una aplicación 100% client side debería poder servirse en cualquier lado

Answer (score 0):

buen día.
Dices que te funciona en desarrollo pero no en producción.

Al parecer la variable $event.target.**files** es llenada en tiempo de ejecución y al momento que se carga la vista(html) no existe aun. Verifica esto declarando que puede ser nulo el valor de la variable o variables, de esta forma cuando sea nulo el valor, simplemente no será invocada la variable o variables. Aca dejo un ejemplo de como agregando **"?"** a la variable se valida un posible null

```
(change)="handleFile($event.target.files)" // original
(change)="handleFile($event.target.files?)" // agregando validación de posible null a files
(change)="handleFile($event.target?.files)" // agregando validación de posible null a target
```

verifica cual te funciona. De ser necesario una validación nula en secuencia opta por:

```
(change)="handleFile($event.target?.files?)" // agregando validación de posible null a target y files secuencialmente
```

Comment: Ninguno de los tres me funcionó (⌣́_⌣̀)